# VB.net Access Update Query

Tags: vb.net, ms-access

VB.net access update query is giving a Syntax Error in Update Query Error. My query is as follows:

```
query = "UPDATE users SET username='" & newUsername & "', password='" & newPassword & "', department='" & newDepartment & "', display_name='" & newDisplayName & "', email='" & newEmail & "', extension='" & newExtension & "', access_level='" & newAccessLevel & "' WHERE id=" & usrID
```

None of the above variables have any symbols at all. What am I doing wrong?

::UPDATE::

```
UPDATE users SET username='alison', password='farm1234',department='1',display_name='Alison *****', email='production@**********.com', extension='1012',access_level='50' WHERE id=1
```

This is what the query runs as.

Comment: The first thing you are doing wrong is exposing yourself to SQL injection attacks... Google it... Next thing you might to is actually run that code, and then give us precisely what is in the variable query...

Comment: I really didn't worry about SQL Injection because the company only is comprised of about 15 people at our home office, none of which know much about this. I was using prepared statements at other times for my SELECT queries, but this was just quicker. Besides you need to login first, which uses the prepared statement. See above for update.

Comment: Never, EVER, assume that you know who as system will be used by. Always code securely. All you need is some manager to decide to put this out wider and suddenly you have a Mission Critical package of software with a fundamental flaw. Oh - and having them log in through a parameterised query is no defence... You assume they want to get past login? What if there intent is merely to drop tables with a machine someone else has kindly / stupidly left logged on...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is caused by the usage of the reserved keyword PASSWORD without enclosing it in square brackets.

Said that, you never use string concatenation to build sql commands, but always a parameterized query to avoid Sql Injection problems but also syntax error in parsing text values (containing single quotes) or decimal values with their decimal separators or dates values.

So, a possible approach to your task could be

```
query = "UPDATE users SET username=?, [password]=?, department=?, " & _
        "display_name=?, email=?, extension=?, access_level=?" & _
        " WHERE id=?"

Using cmd = new OleDbCommand(query, connection)
   cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p1", newUsername)
   cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p2", newPassword)   
   cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p3", newDepartment)   
   cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p4", newDisplayName)
   cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p5", newEmail)
   cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p6", newExtension)
   cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p7", newAccessLevel)   
   cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p8", usrID)
   cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()

End Using
```

Keep in mind that OleDb doesn't use the parameter names to find the corresponding placeholder in sql command text. Instead it uses a positional progression and thus adding the parameters to the collection should respect the order in which the parameter appears in the sql command text

Comment: See my comment above. I guess after re-reading, my comment doesn't apply. Well, I needed to know that passwords had to be enclosed anyways.

Answer (score 0):

```
   ConStr()
    Qry="UPDATE users SET username=@uname, [password]=@pass, department=@dept, " & _
            "display_name=@dnam, email=@email, extension=@ext, access_level=@acslvl" & _
            " WHERE id=@id"
    cmd = new oledbcommand(Qry,Conn)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@uname",newUsername)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pass",newPassword)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dept",newDepartment)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dnam",newDisplayName)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@email",newEmail)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ext",newExtension)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@acslvl",newAccessLevel)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id",usrID)
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
```